# Django Local Host works but hosting servers don't

Tags: python, html, django, localhost, web-hosting

I'm really new to programming. I had to make a web application with Django, so I made a weather app.
It works fine if I run it locally with runserver but I tried various hosting websites and none work.

[This is my GitHub Repository.](https://github.com/Pfefferdorn/Pfefferdorn.github.io)

I hope anyone can help me.

Various hosting websites.
Want my application to work online but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

there I check your GitHub repo and I realize that you haven't configured your project according to vercel(hosting provider) documentation.

Head over to the documentation and follow the instructions
https://vercel.com/templates/python/django-hello-world

Comment: I change everything like on the website but it still doesn't work.
Could it be that it can't show/use the templates/weather.html?

Oh and I know about the security key stuff but it's just an assignment I have to do, even though I'm completely new to this.